# Как запустить Flask приложение с Apache на MacOS Mojave? Ошибка «Invalid command 'WSGIProcessGroup'

Tags: python, flask, apache2, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

На новом ноутбуку с MacOS Mojave пытаюсь развернуть Flask–приложение, которе работает через Apache. Сделал все, как на другой машине с предыдущей ОС. При запуске команды

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl configtest
```

Получаю ошибку

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/my_app.conf:
>   Invalid command 'WSGIProcessGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что предустановленный apache–сервер (httpd) на MacOS Mojave идет без WSGI–модуля. Как решение проблемы можно собрать `mod_wsgi` из [исходного кода](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases). Но есть нюанс. Для сборки необходимы библиотеки разработчика для apache2, которых я не нашел для MacOS. В частности, для сборки нужна команд `apxs`.

Хак заключается в том, чтобы установить `httpd` через `brew`, который поставляется с `apxs`

```
brew install httpd
```

После этого можно собрать `mod_wsgi` из исходников. Чтобы не было проблем с правами доступа, при установке нужно указать локацию для модулей стандартного httpd

```
sudo make install LIBEXECDIR='/usr/libexec/apache2'
```

Затем в `httpd.conf` добавляем загрузку модуля

```
LoadModule wsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
```

Готово!