# Apache не видит Flask: 'ImportError: No module named flask'

Tags: python, apache, macos, flask, mod-wsgi

Разворачиваю Flask приложение на MacOS Mojave с использованием `Apache2` и `mod_wsgi`. Apache настроил, как рассказано в [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/997402/6).

Wsgi–скрипт подхватывается, но приложение не работает. В логах ошибок вижу

```
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

*Важно*: Если я использую утилиту wsgi–модуля, то приложение успешно стартует:

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server my_app.wsgi
```

Как мне кажется, есть вероятность, что предустановленный apache как–то недонастроен. Flask лежит в папке анакодны

```
$ which flask
```

Возвращает

> /development/anaconda2/bin/flask

Wsgi–скрипт

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/share')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/share/my_app')

def application(environ, start_response):

    from my_app import app as _application
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

Файл конфигурации apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin nicolas@chabanovsky.com

        DocumentRoot "/usr/local/share/my_app"
        ServerName my_app.ru

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

        WSGIDaemonProcess my_app python-path=/usr/local/share/my_app:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ processes=15 threads=30 maximum-requests=100 deadlock-timeout=60
        WSGIProcessGroup my_app
        WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/share/my_app/my_app.wsgi

        Alias /m/ /usr/local/share/my_app/static/m/

        <Directory "/usr/local/share/my_app/static/m/">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/usr/local/share/my_app/">
                AllowOverride All
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/my_app_error.log"
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/my_app_warning.log" combined

        SetEnv LOCALE_LANGUAGE_NAME ru
</VirtualHost>
```

*Обновление*

Пробовал посмотреть какие пути есть в `$PYTHONPATH`, когда через стандартную утилиту запускаю (писал выше), а потом передать их через python-path в конфигурационном файле. В этом случае в логах ошибка:

> from _weakref import (
>   ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

**Обновление 2**

Посмотрел опять вывод в случае двух подходов (с утилитой и через apache).

```
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
```

Apache

```
/development/anaconda2/bin/python
2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)]
```

mod_wsgi-express start-server my_app.wsgi

```
/usr/sbin/httpd
2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
```

При этом питон у меня вроде бы один

```
 which python
```

Возвращает

> /development/anaconda2/bin/python

Если запустить интерпретатор, можно видеть следующее:

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
```

Подскажите, как так может быть?

Comment: В конфиге вроде как нет пути до самого транслятора Питона, только до библиотек. Соответственно, если на компе установлено несколько Питонов, то может использоваться неверный. С Apache я не работал, но обычно в проектах на Питоне в конфиге пишут путь до исполняемого файла Питона, притом часто сразу в виртуальном окружении вроде VirtualEnv – тогда нужные модули будут гарантированно подключены.

Comment: @AivanF. Спасибо! Не могли бы вы в ответе привести пример того, о чем вы говорите?

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге вроде как нет пути до самого транслятора Питона, только до библиотек. Следовательно, если на компьютере установлено несколько версий Питона, то может использоваться неверная, в которой нет Flask'а. С Apache я не работал, но обычно в проектах на Питоне в конфиге пишут путь до исполняемого файла Питона.

И очень часто используются виртуальные среды (например [VirtualEnv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)) – они позволяют инкапсулироовать нужные для конкретного проекта модули (как Docker, но проще и компактнее). Также они создают особый для проекта исполняемый файл Питона, при запуске которого подгружаются библиотеки проекта.

Судя по [по этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451634/5308802) из enSO, для настройки Apache Вам следует использовать команды **`WSGIPythonHome`** и возможно ещё `WSGIPythonPath` для указания пути до нужного исполняемого файла Питона и его библиотек.

Тогда остаётся лишь подписать путь до нужного системного исполняемого файла Питона или (чуть сложнее, но более качественно) настроить виртуальное окружение Питона, установить нужные модули туда, и прописать путь уже до проектно-специфического Питона.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.